# IEEE 802.1AE (MACSec) support

Tags: security

Does Android support [IEEE802.1AE MACSec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1AE) ?

This protocol enables data confidentiality and integrity over WiFi connections.